# Servicing DT Swiss 240 FRONT hub

Tags: maintenance, hub

this is my first post here. How can I service a DT swiss 240 front hub, as in remove the adapter ( end cap ) to get to the insides? Do i need a special tool? Does it even need servicing? There is plenty of info out there on how to service the rear hub and I have already done that but I can't find anything on servicing the front hub. Please help.

Comment: Did you look at the technical manual from DT Swiss (available on their website) for this hub? It'll be in the same file as the one for the rear hub (https://www.dtswiss.com/Resources/Support/HUBS/DT-Swiss-Hubs-240s-Technical-Manual).

Comment: Thanks. And yes I did look the manual but it doesn't explain how to remove the endcap.

Answer (score 4):

The DT Swiss 240s front hub is a sealed bearing hub.  Service includes removing the endcaps, removing the bearing seals, regreasing the bearing cartridge, and then reversing the process.

There are no special tools required.  The end caps are a friction fit, and, while they are tight, they will remove by hand.

If bearings are damaged, replace the entire cartridge.

This does require special tools. Or at least, strongly recommend them.:)

One last thing:  If there is nothing wrong with the hub, no service is required.

[image]

Comment: So when they recommend servicing your hubs a few times a year, they only mean the rear?

Comment: They don't recommend "a few times a year".  They recommend once a year.  Issues generally only appear in the rear freehub, since the bearings there are the most exposed, and under the most direct load.  The front hub will need greased or replacement bearings once a year, more in wet or muddy riding conditions.

Comment: For many riders, a year is probably even too frequent.

Comment: Thanks zenbike, you've been very helpful. Yes the end caps are very tight, I was having trouble getting them off. That is basically the reason for my post. I figured they were removable by hand as are the rear, just wanted to be sure.

Comment: Yeah, they are often tight enough to need an axle vise to grip them for removal, to prevent cosmetic damage.  But it's just a dry o-ring inside the axle cap that causes it to bind.  Wipe a light coat of grease on those o-rings (1 each side) and it will be easier next time.